# Deploying cron.yaml or cron.xml to Google App Engine via REST api

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a cron job to google app engine using only REST api exposed by google cloud api. So far I have been able to deploy my application (java8,war) using the rest api and it works nicely. The problem is that the app deployment via rest ignores the cron job built into the application archieve. I was wondering if someone has achieved the same and could point me to the right direction/documentations.